# WordPress Nav with dynamic copyright

Tags: wordpress, nav

I`d like to make copyright into the nav like this:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array(
    'items_wrap' => '
    <ul id="menu-metamenue" class="menu">
    <li id="copyright-head"><span>©&copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> 

    <?php bloginfo('name'); ?></span></li>
    %3$s</ul>',

    'theme_location'=> 'meta_menu'
));
?>
```

Thanks for your help
Ogni

Comment: Where are you having issues with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already in a PHP block (and in the middle of a string), so another `<?php` won't do what you need.  Try something like:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array(
    'items_wrap' => '
    <ul id="menu-metamenue" class="menu">
    <li id="copyright-head"><span>©&copy; ' . date('Y') . ' ' . get_bloginfo('name') . '</span></li>
    %3$s</ul>',

    'theme_location'=> 'meta_menu'
));
?>
```

Comment: Thanks: copyright and year works fine, just blogname goes out of the `ul li` into the wraping `div` of the navi, looks very strange.

Comment: Ah see my edit.  Use `get_bloginfo` instead of `bloginfo`.  You want the value returned (so you can include it in the string you're building up), not `echo`ed straight to the screen.